# How to determine if a build is queued but not started in the TFS2010 API?

Tags: c#, tfs, build

Im using the enum Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildStatus for each  and it works great for the statuses contained in it.

But is there a blatantly obvious way of determining if a build is queued, but not yet in progress? I know the build explorer in visual studio can see this, im having problems getting that data programmatically.

Do i have to check something on the teamproject instead of the IBuildDetail itself? Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it doesn't appear that `IBuildDetailSpec` queries ever return queued builds.  However, you can use the `IQueuedBuildSpec` interface to query for queued builds.

For example:

```
public IEnumerable<IQueuedBuild> getQueuedBuilds(TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsCollection, string teamProject)
{
    // Get instance of build server service from TFS
    IBuildServer buildServer = tfsCollection.GetService<IBuildServer>();

    // Set up query
    IQueuedBuildSpec spec = buildServer.CreateBuildQueueSpec(teamProject);
    spec.Status = QueueStatus.Queued;

    // Execute query
    IQueuedBuildQueryResult result = buildServer.QueryQueuedBuilds(spec);

    // Array of queued builds will be in the result.QueuedBuilds property
    return result.QueuedBuilds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see the build status as `BuildStatus.NotStarted` once the build actually reaches the queue.  There is a time before it reaches the queue that it really doesn't have a status, though.

If you're submitting your build programmatically, you can do:

```
bool success = queue.WaitForBuildStart(pollingIntervalInMilliseconds, timeOutInMilliseconds);
```

As long as the agent is listening, this should actually return very quickly.  If you have a slow network, this could potentially take a couple seconds for handshaking.

Once it passes the WaitForBuildStart, the status is set to `BuildStatus.NotStarted` until it moves to `InProgress` and the rest of the way down the line.

Comment: Well it seems that the builds on the definition never get the status set to NotStarted, it is only the queued build (IqueuedBuild) that is returned from IBuildServer.QueueBuild that have the correct status.

Interestingly enough the builds on the definition get set to Inprogress once started. I suppose that is correct though since the new doesnt actually exist before it is in progress

Comment: It also seems that WaitForBuildStart actually does what it say, it waits until the build starts, so I had no luck using that either.

Answer (score 0):

@Greg Case
First thank you for the code , you gave me the solution that I was searching for. Second , I want to suggest using the same code snippet of yours to receive notifications from TFS for specific Queued build. I already used it to get notified that the build I queued is completed and it even returns exception details for failure case . To do that you need to connect() to the queued build returned from code and then register event , I wanted to add it as a comment but couldn't for long text

```
IQueuedBuild CurrentBuild =  result.QueuedBuilds.First();
CurrentBuild.Connect(); 
CurrentBuild.PollingCompleted += CurrentBuild_PollingCompleted;
```